# Unable to perform a JDBC request for phpmyadmin database (No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ck)

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jmeter

I am unable to perform a JDBC request to database in `phpMyAdmin`. I'm using Xampp just to learn how to perform a JDBC request using Jmeter.

This is the configuration I have used in the JDBC config element(Jmeter version is 2.10)

```
variable name: mydb
JDBC URL:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ck -- where ck is the name of the database
JDBC Driver Class: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
Username: c
Password: c
```

the user has all privileges on the database.

I have set the same variable name in JDBC request and using a simple select query `select * from table1`

But when I ran the test, I got the following error

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ck
```

I have already extracted the JDBC driver for mysql in the lib folder

```
mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin
```

This is the Driver.

Is there something I am missing. the `java` version I am using is `1.7.0_45-b18`?

I tried a lot of things and saw similar issues but previous solutions did not fit.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a database *client*, not a database server

Comment: Can you please suggest a way how can i test a JDBC request for learning purposes? and isn't it possible to make a JDBC request to a DATABASE CLIENT

Comment: No, it would be like one web browser asking another web browser to give it a web page. You need to connect to the MySQL server that phpMyAdmin connects to.

Comment: Can you please tell me How can i connect to the MySQL server that phpmyadmin connects to. Thanks

Comment: Ravinder told you how half an hour ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class names are case sensitive.

**Change**:

```
JDBC Driver Class: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
```

**To**:

```
JDBC Driver Class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

And `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin` is no the Driver class. But `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` is a java class library that allows to communicate with `MySQL`.

Make sure that this `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` exists in the lib path of the application in your `Java IDE`.

Comment: Thanks Ravinder . Case sensitivity was the issue. Thanks a tonn. I spend hours trying other things and overlooked it. Really appreciate the help